# MongoDB Concurrency Lock Failed for Multithread

Tags: java, multithreading, mongodb, concurrency, locks

I did some test on MongoDB from java multithread program to check how MongoDB ensure concurrent access on document. My sample program ensure that only one copy will exists on collection. it inserts a document if it not exists in collection otherwise it updates document frequency. After several tests i found that some documents exists with same value.

**Collection Design**

```
{
   _id: ObjectID,
   doc: String,
   doc_freq: Integer
}
```

Here "doc" field is used for searching and if anything found then "doc_freq" is updated. If nothing is found then new document will be inserted.

**Implementation**

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoDB.getDatabase(DB_NAME).getCollection(COLLECTION);

Document incUpdate = new Document("doc_freq", doc.count());

Document setUpdate = new Document("doc", doc.data());

Document update = new Document();
update.append("$setOnInsert", setUpdate);
update.append("$inc", incUpdate);

UpdateOptions updateOptions = new UpdateOptions();
updateOptions.upsert(true);

Document query = new Document("doc", doc.data());

collection.updateOne(query, update, updateOptions)
```

I have inserted 100000 entries which has same doc value and used 200 thread. And found that more than one entries found on collection with same doc value. I have used **Java MongoDB Driver Version: 3.0.4** and **MongoDB Version:3.2.1** on OS Yosemite

Comment: Which engine are you using? MMAP or Wired Tiger? What you are suggesting is that multiple "upserts" for the same value are being issued at the same time, resulting in multiple documents. It would be better if you could produce a full listing that reproduces this. Also try setting a unique index on "doc" to see if you start getting duplicate key errors.

Comment: Thanks Blakes for your reply. I'm using Wired Tiger. Yes, i can bypass this issue by creating unique index. I also tried using method  **findOneAndUpdate** which creating duplicates much fewer than method  **updateOne**. I also added a new field which stores document creation time and found there are millisecs difference between duplicate documents. Rather than unique index  do you have any other suggestion to resolve this problem ? MongoDB should handle this scenario,  what you think Blakes ?

Comment: Again, if this is **really** happening then I would personally love to see your code to reproduce. And believe me that where the case is indeed reproducible, I will be sharing with the core development team until a solution is found. But we need your code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please find my test code on this [link](https://bitbucket.org/talha13/duplicatetest.git) . To reproduce this case please  run several times. Before each run please clear doc collection. I have created this project using **Netbeans Version: 8.0.2**

Comment: @BlakesSeven do you have any updates ?